# Connecting to SQL Server in Visual C#

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, visual-studio-2012

I'll show the code I'm using, but I can't connect to SQL Server through Visual C#. I have installed what came in the C# package and I keep getting this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error
>   occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was
>   not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a
>   connection to SQL Server)

I can't figure out how to connect to the server. I'm using Windows 8, SQL Sever 2012 (Visual Studio 2012) and if I go to connect in the top toolbar, it doesn't matter if I use (local), localhost or my IP address. I can't figure this out and its driving me nuts! Here's my code, if it helps.

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection sqlConnection1 =
         new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Server=(local);Database=Database1DataSet;Trusted_Connection=True;");

    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT VALUES (id, Medname, MedDose, MedAm, MedNoon, MedEve, MedNight, MedPRN, MedOther) VALUES (1, 'Clonazepam', '2mg', 'true', 'true', 'false', 'true', 'true', 'false')";
    cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

    sqlConnection1.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sqlConnection1.Close();
}
```

Thanks so much. This is my first time using SQL Server through Visual Studio.

Comment: Have you verified that SQL Server is actually installed and running via Services and/or Task Manager? I assume you mean by "SQL Sever 2012 (Visual Studio 2012)" that you chose the option to install "SQL Server Express LocalDB" when installing Visual Studio, right? The issue here is that SQL Server is either not installed, installed but not running, or not configured to communicate via Named Pipes.

Comment: question asked so many times, and in some many ways.

Comment: Check your Client Protocols setting in Sql Server Configuration Manager and confirm that the proper ones are enabled (enable all if you are sure it's secure on your machine to do so). (After confirming what @scrutzky said first of course )

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chaitanya_medikonduri/archive/2011/03/09/sql-server-connectivity-issues-troubleshooting-tips.aspx

Comment: Actually, if this is SQL Server Express LocalDB, there probably won't be an entry in the services list. In Visual Studio, go to the VIEW menu and select `SQL Server Object Explorer`. Is anything in that list? Also, if it is LocalDB, the "server" in the connection string is more like "(localdb)\V11" or "(localdb)\Projects".

Comment: local should be localhost? I'm not sure tough.

Comment: @sturcotte06 : no, "(local)" is the technically appropriate SQL Server notation to get the default instance. But "localhost" usually works just as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed SQL Server as part of the Visual Studio 2012 install process, then it installed **SQL Server Express LocalDB**. LocalDB is very lightweight and does not have a constantly running service. If you actually did install LocalDB while installing Visual Studio, you should be able to see the "instance" by going to the *View* menu in Visual Studio and selecting *SQL Server Object Explorer*. There should be a folder (so to speak) for "SQL Server" and expanding that should show you something along the lines of:

`(localdb)\V11`
or
`(localdb)\Projects`

Whatever that value is, THAT is what you specify for the "server=" in the connection string. So, your connection string should look more like this (due to the backslash, you should prefix the string with `@`):

`@"Server=(localdb)\V11;Database=Database1DataSet;Trusted_Connection=True;"`

Also, when you create a new project in Visual Studio, it should pre-populate the correct connection string in the *Debug* tab of *Project Properties*.

**EDIT:**
Also, you can find the instance name(s) in the following location as each instance will be a subfolder:

`C:\Users\{YourUserName}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances`

Comment: Hello, thank you. I was getting that when I played with the SQL settings in the toolbar. I'll try that out. I'm currently installing SQL Server 2012 off of the Microsoft site. I needed to put two \\ after (localdb)

Comment: @sandorfalot : I am confused. You were getting what when you played with what SQL settings? What SQL Server are you installing? Express? Are you also installing Express LocalDB? What do you mean you got an error "under Projects"? I will add something to my answer to help find the instance name.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I've got SQL Express LocalDB installed, its currently connecting to the database but asking for a username and password. So I've got the main part fixed - I can connect to the database.

Comment: @sandorfalot : I just updated my answer again regarding why you had to use two backslashes. Meaning, might be better to prefix the connect string with `@`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that. It's now asking me for a username and password, and I have no idea what to use. I'm using Windows auth but it won't take that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63377/discussion-between-srutzky-and-sandorfalot).

Comment: @sandorfalot : did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: Yes I did. I installed SQL Server 2014 from Microsoft's site, did the updates in Visual Studio and it works now!